How to effectively bootstrap SQL database with millions of records, when you are almost guaranteed to make mistakes?
I am playing with a side project which, for purposes of this question, is a multi-language dictionary, including 100+ languages, each with 100k+ entries, where each entry can have 1-5+ pronunciations, 1-2+ transcriptions, and then I have "search" records for optimizing prefix/suffix searches, etc.. It ends up being over a million records per language.
It takes about 5 minutes to seed the database with 1 language on production. That is fast enough. It takes about 1 minute to generate the seed data from a bunch of messy data files, like in this hacked-together 500-line+ Tibetan cleaning script.
When I clean the data files for a language, I am doing several of the following (at least!):

normalizing unicode characters, so there aren't weird characters, trailing whitespace, etc..
create/clean pronunciations from text or IPA phonetic transcription (which is a task I am continuously improving on)
clean the transcriptions
merge similar records from different places
make sure to set the appropriate properties on each entry
etc..

Each of these (and there are a few more steps) is prone to error. In Tibetan just now, I realized there were two tsheg characters (syllable separators): ་ and ༌ (can you tell the difference?! no, they look the same, but are for some reason different unicode points). I only discovered this after seeding the database for 5 minutes and seeing the data in the web UI.
This has happened over and over again as I discover things that I missed while cleaning, across languages.
Bootstrapping a database from scratch is fast (like I mentioned). But updating the database is SLOW, 1 record at a time, for a million potential records, plus merging data, etc.. I have just been truncating the table and starting over (since the site is not live yet).
What are my options in terms of workflow here? (Not my question for you)

I can truncate the table and start over. This means my data can't be live or else it might get deleted (have to truncate ALL languages). I don't want to have partitions per language as I have about 20 tables dependent on the main dictionary entry (all of which would have to be partitioned), and there are 1000's of languages in real life, even though I'm only going to have 100k+ records for about 100 languages. I will still have a few hundred/thousand records for the remaining languages.
I can clean my data and save into massive JSON files (which I'm already doing, which is what I use to seed the database). But it's hard to check that everything is correct. And still, I can't officially publish the data to the public / web until it's PERFECT.
I can iterate on the data in the database, waiting for days as it updates 1 language after one small tweak, which will use a lot of IO and take hours to complete (costing time and money for the database provider I'm using). This is too painfully slow.

So I guess those are the main options.
My question for you is, how can I more thoroughly check and prepare/clean my data, so when I upload it to the production db it is PERFECT, and I don't need to fix anything again? What sort of workflow tricks can I use to achieve perfection when it comes to processing my data?
I feel like it's like being a jet pilot. You have to have a checklist that you run through otherwise you might forget to check a switch or toggle, etc.. You can't rely on your memory, you need that sheet. But in my case, I don't know what items should even be on the checklist? Maybe I first create a checklist, add to it, refine it, write my cleaning script, and then publish? And if I make a mistake, well then I have to wait until I update my checklist again?
I'm not sure.
What can offer me the best of both worlds?

Easily update data in production.
Allow me to make mistakes and not have to PERFECT all data in advance.


Why exactly can't you truncate the data and start all over from time to time after the database was made live? Are you planning to have other tables with foreign key references to the dictionary? If yes, then please tell us why.

Yes, each dictionary entry has_many pronunciations, has_many transcriptions, has_many definitions, etc.. So those are all separate tables.

That's not an explanation why you cannot start all over. Come on, I am sure you can give us a better explanation.

What do you mean? Because I have ~20 tables dependent on the main entry table, when I need to update data, I have to update hundreds of thousands of records individually. Doesn't that make sense? It is extremely slow.

After rereading your question, I think this sounds more like a problem of the specific SQLs and relational DBMS technology. Some kind of paritioning per language is probably the way to go, it is probably not exactly the kind of partitioning you have in mind.

Have you considered tracking the updates/changes made over the built dataset, that you can use as part of your build process to create a brand new seeded + updates dataset?

As @DocBrown says, why can't you use your fast regen process? eg

messy data files
process to new DB - 5min
launch site
notice error and fix process - X Days
reprocess data with updated process to new DB - 5 min
switch live site to point at new DB - 0.1 sec

In regard to getting it perfect. I would add some unit tests, it hard to exactly what without detailed knowledge but maybe

Sample Tibetan word has 10 synonyms in result set.
Sample sentence has these exact punctuation characters included
All generated pronunciations match this regex for syntactically correct text

Also, just checked out your cleaning script and noticed
id: uuidv4(),

Now I love GUIDs, but here it might be the wrong choice. If you want to be able to update parts of the db then you need to be able to generate the same id for a target word from the base data each time. Which you can't do if its random every time you process the raw data.
Even if you allow that homographs will be a problem, most words just using some normalised version of the actual word might allow you to significantly speed up the update process as you will be able to search and join on the PK
